# Cloudrail - OneDrive API : Advanced search request fails

Tags: node.js, onedrive, cloudrail

I'm using cloudrail Node.Js v2.17.3.

I have to do an advanced request on OneDrive API.

The authentication part and getting/storing credentials have succeeded.
Here is the request I have to do (according to OneDrive's doc):
/drive/root/search(q='IMG_001.jpg')

Of course, the file is present in my OneDrive account.

Here is the code :

```
const req = new cloudrail.types.AdvancedRequestSpecification("/drive/root/search(q='IMG_001.jpg')");
req.setMethod("GET");
req.setHeaders({"Content-Type": "application/json"});
service.advancedRequest(req, (err, res) => {
   console.log(err, res);
});
```

Err.message says : "Invalid API or resource".

However, when I try the simple request "/drive/root/children", it works...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft recently introduced their new Graph API which is used by all of the services as far as I know. So the documentation you are referring to is for the new API. 
Try using '/drive/items/{the_folder_id or root}/view.search?q=txt' instead. You also might need to url encode the parameter. So the safest solution would probably be sth like that:

```
const url = "/drive/items/root/view.search?q=" + encodeURIComponent("[search query]");
const req = new cloudrail.types.AdvancedRequestSpecification(url);
req.setMethod("GET");
service.advancedRequest(req, (err, res) => {
    console.log(err, res);
});
```